# Django run on the wrong port

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, wagtail

Currently pushing a wagtail cms - Django app to a clever cloud server.
Django is using the wrong port.

```
2019-02-13T00:00:19+01:00 No application detected yet
2019-02-13T00:00:20+01:00 DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 2541) died :( trying respawn ...
2019-02-13T00:00:20+01:00 Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 2545)
2019-02-13T00:00:20+01:00 /home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.#012 """)
2019-02-13T00:00:20+01:00 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x5653f4f4ca40 pid: 2545 (default app)
2019-02-13T00:00:22+01:00 Error: Deployment timed out after 180s. Please contact the support
2019-02-13T00:00:22+01:00 b88afb7e-c5b2-4aa5-b1f5-c0d31b8f6f75 nginx: 2019/02/12 23:00:22 [error] 1901#0: *129 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
2019-02-13T00:00:22+01:00 !!! uWSGI process 2545 got Segmentation Fault !!!
2019-02-13T00:00:22+01:00 GET localhost:8080/ returned 502!
 Deploy failed
2019-02-13T00:00:22+01:00 No application detected yet
2019-02-13T00:00:22+01:00 *** backtrace of 2545 ***#012uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2a) [0x5653f32225ca]#012uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x23) [0x5653f3222983]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6(+0x37d00) [0x7fdeacc98d00]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(ssl3_cleanup_key_block+0xb) [0x7fde93021cab]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(ssl3_clear+0x16) [0x7fde9301f5a6]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(tls1_clear+0x9) [0x7fde9302b219]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libssl.so.1.1(SSL_new+0x445) [0x7fdeaf3a1955]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0x23969) [0x7fde932b6969]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0x24fc5) [0x7fde932b7fc5]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(PQconnectPoll+0xb78) [0x7fde932a1ba8]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0xfa28) [0x7fde932a2a28]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(PQconnectdb+0x1f) [0x7fde932a541f]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x12b01) [0x7fde934f6b01]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1388f) [0x7fde934f788f]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xdc228) [0x7fdeac841228]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x8d) [0x7fdeac7f846d]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x937d6) [0x7fdeac7f87d6]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_CallFunction_SizeT+0x8c) [0x7fdeac7f8a6c]#012/home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0xc258) [0x7fde934f0258]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0xfd) [0x7fdeac7f961d]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x77ba) [0x7fdeac7d8d3a]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x932) [0x7fdeac8ac742]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x1bb) [0x7fdeac7f74bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x13a7) [0x7fdeac7d2927]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7d2a) [0x7fdeac7d92aa]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7d2a) [0x7fdeac7d92aa]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7d2a) [0x7fdeac7d92aa]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x932) [0x7fdeac8ac742]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallKeywords+0x93) [0x7fdeac7f7673]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7d2a) [0x7fdeac7d92aa]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7d2a) [0x7fdeac7d92aa]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x932) [0x7fdeac8ac742]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallKeywords+0x93) [0x7fdeac7f7673]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x6250) [0x7fdeac7d77d0]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xa2ae6) [0x7fdeac807ae6]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xac820) [0x7fdeac811820]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xac9fc) [0x7fdeac8119fc]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xdc228) [0x7fdeac841228]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallKeywords+0xd5) [0x7fdeac7f7d85]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5107) [0x7fdeac7d6687]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7d2a) [0x7fdeac7d92aa]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x2db) [0x7fdeac7f75db]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xda414) [0x7fdeac83f414]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xe02f3) [0x7fdeac8452f3]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(PyObject_GetIter+0x19) [0x7fdeac7e4679]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xac7d0) [0x7fdeac8117d0]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xac9fc) [0x7fdeac8119fc]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0xdc228) [0x7fdeac841228]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallKeywords+0xd5) [0x7fdeac7f7d85]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5107) [0x7fdeac7d6687]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x69c5) [0x7fdeac7d7f45]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x817c) [0x7fdeac7d96fc]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7d2a) [0x7fdeac7d92aa]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x6b3bb) [0x7fdeac7d03bb]#012/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x2db) [0x7fdeac7f75db]#012*** end of backtrace ***
 Deploy failed in 4 minutes and 31 seconds. Please review the lines above to find out why
2019-02-13T00:00:23+01:00 DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 2545) died :( trying respawn ...
2019-02-13T00:00:23+01:00 /home/bas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.#012 """)
2019-02-13T00:00:23+01:00 Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 2549)
2019-02-13T00:00:23+01:00 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x5653f4f4ca40 pid: 2549 (default app)
2019-02-13T00:00:27+01:00 Good bye!
2019-02-13T00:00:27+01:00 Time to clean up and say good bye.
```

- I have created a `.init` file (at the settings folder with base.py,production.py, dev.py)

with

```
   [uwsgi]
    http =  0.0.0.0:8080
    master = True
    processes = 2
    threads = 2
    module = myapp.wsgi:application
```

the result is the same. The same app is going well on heroku. I never got this error before

Answer (score 0):

Since the error seems to be related with CleverCloud try this example application that should work on CleverCloud.

[Django + Clever-Cloud](https://github.com/CleverCloud/demo-django)